# simple sql query respect to 2 column and single table

Tags: sql, oracle

table name `doctor_dtl`

```
column 1 name doc_code
column 2 name doctor_name
```

problem: same doc_name are inserted multiple time and multiple doc_code are generated against that all same name so doctor name duplicated but there doc_code are different i want a query where i can display all duplicate doctor name and all doctor code?
example:

```
         john doc0001
         john doc0010
         amit doc0006
         amit doc1000
         amit doc1010
```

i want this type of output to be display

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a11.doctor_name, a11.doc_code 
from doctor_dtl a11 join (select
doctor_name, count(doctor_name)  from doctor_dtl Group by doctor_name having
count(doctor_name) > 1  ) a12 on a11.doctor_name = a12.doctor_name group
by a11.doctor_name, a11.doc_code
```

Comment: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement showing on group by

Comment: my query select a11.DOC_ACT_NAME, a11.DOC_CD
from RCP_DOCTOR_DTL_MST  a11
join (select DOC_ACT_NAME, count(DOC_ACT_NAME)
from RCP_DOCTOR_DTL_MST Group by DOC_ACT_NAME having (count(DOC_ACT_NAME) > 1 ) a12 
join on a11.DOC_ACT_NAME = a12.DOC_ACT_NAME group by a11.DOC_ACT_NAME, a11.DOC_CD

Comment: @SHOWMIKSETTA :- Please remove left parenthesis which is placed between having and count also remove join keyword after a12, because it is already after a11.

Comment: select a11.DOC_ACT_NAME, a11.DOC_CD
from RCP_DOCTOR_DTL_MST  a11
join (select DOC_ACT_NAME, count(DOC_ACT_NAME)
from RCP_DOCTOR_DTL_MST Group by DOC_ACT_NAME having count(DOC_ACT_NAME) > 1 ) a12 
join on a11.DOC_ACT_NAME = a12.DOC_ACT_NAME group by a11.DOC_ACT_NAME, a11.DOC_CD

Comment: select a11.DOC_ACT_NAME, a11.DOC_CD 
from RCP_DOCTOR_DTL_MST a11 
join (select DOC_ACT_NAME, count(DOC_ACT_NAME) 
from RCP_DOCTOR_DTL_MST Group by DOC_ACT_NAME 
having count(DOC_ACT_NAME) > 1 ) 
a12 on a11.DOC_ACT_NAME = a12.DOC_ACT_NAME 
group by a11.DOC_ACT_NAME, a11.DOC_CD

Answer (score 1):

You can use it.

```
SELECT 
    doc_code,
    doctor_name 
FROM doctor_dtl
WHERE doctor_name IN (
    SELECT 
    doctor_name
    FROM doctor_dtl
    GROUP BY doctor_name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

[Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f73a5/4)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach if you are working `SQL Server`

```
SELECT doc_code,
       doctor_name
FROM
(
    SELECT doc_code,
           doctor_name,
           COUNT(doctor_name) OVER(PARTITION BY doctor_name) [Count]
    FROM <table_name>
) a
WHERE [Count] > 1;
```

Result :

```
doc_code    doctor_name
doc0006     amit
doc1000     amit
doc1010     amit
doc0001     john
doc0010     john
```

Comment: ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: cursor on [Count]